# Postgres: variable saying from which schema I select

Tags: postgresql, select

I have created a SQL SELECT to get all enums and their values in a schema:

```
SELECT 
    t.typname, array_agg(e.enumlabel) 
FROM pg_type t
JOIN pg_enum e ON t.oid = e.enumtypid
JOIN pg_namespace n ON t.typnamespace = n.oid
WHERE t.typtype = 'e' AND n.nspname = 'public'
GROUP BY typname
```

I have put the select into a view so I dont have to write it everytime I want to call it. The only thing that bothers me is that if I rename the schema or use it in another schema I have to rewrite the name of the schema manually, check line 6 of the code:

```
    WHERE t.typtype = 'e' AND n.nspname = 'public'
```

Public is hardtyped there. When selecting in postgres, is there a "global" variable saying from which schema you select? I was not able to find any.

Thanks

PS: I use postgres 8.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current schema can be retrieved using the function `current_schema()`

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for and thanks for correcting the spelling :) I am always confused whether to use Postgre or Postgres

Comment: Well, officially it is PostgreSQL, but Postgres is a popular nickname.  Even many of those who use the official spelling *pronounce* it like the shorter form.  (I do.)  http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#What_is_PostgreSQL.3F_How_is_it_pronounced.3F_What_is_Postgres.3F

Comment: @Santhos: In addtion to kgrittn's comment: Postgre (without the s) is **never** right

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to wiring the schema or looking it up with current_schema(), you could make your view group by schema as well and then select on the view.

```
create or replace view enum_vw as
SELECT 
    n.nspname, t.typname, array_agg(e.enumlabel) 
FROM pg_type t
JOIN pg_enum e ON t.oid = e.enumtypid
JOIN pg_namespace n ON t.typnamespace = n.oid
WHERE t.typtype = 'e'
GROUP BY n.nspname, t.typname;

select * from enum_vw where nspname = 'public';
```

Comment: That would work too, but I want a clean look: enum_name => enum_values. The name of the namespace does not interest me much. I only need to make it work under every schema, that is why current_schema() is the thing i was looking for. Anyway, I appreciate your asnwer. Thanks